# Link de Storage en Laravel no funciona en producion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, filezilla

Estoy usando storage_path para guardar mis imágenes y simbólicamente mi carpeta de almacenamiento para public_html

```
php artisan storage:link
```

En el local, todo funciona bien, cuando subo una imagen, se cargará en la carpeta de almacenamiento y el enlace aparecerá en la carpeta pública, pero desde que me moví al modo de host y producción en vivo, mis imágenes se cargarán en la carpeta de almacenamiento, pero no hay nada en mi public_html / almacenamiento y no puedo conseguirlos en mi front-end.

```
/config/filesystems.php

'public' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => storage_path('app/public/'),
  'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
  'visibility' => 'public',
],

.env

FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

Ejemplo del Controlador

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
  $image = $request->file('image');
  $filename = 'page' . '-' . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $location = storage_path('app/public/images/' . $filename);
  Image::make($image)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);
  if(!empty($page->image)){
    Storage::delete('images/' . $page->image);
  }
  $page->image = $filename;            
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionas que pasaste de un ambiente a otro, y si por ejemplo, comprimiste el proyecto y lo subiste, lo descomprimiste y ya, debes de crear nuevamente el link simbólico desde el nuevo servidor:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Ya que probablemente ahorita tengas una copia de la carpeta a la que originalmente estaba apuntando ese enlace simbólico y no el enlace como tal.

Answer (score 1):

pudes hacerlo asi:
no es necesario definir un `storage` para una carpeta publica puedes hacer solo referencia al `public_path()`
esto nos devolvera la ruta de la carpeta publica que seria `app/public`
ahora solo le pasamos imagenes `public_path('/images/');`
tambien te recomiendo utilizar `uniqid()` en caso de que se suban 2 imagenes al mismo tiempo!

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
  $image = $request->file('image');
  $filename = 'page' . '-' . uniqid() . time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
  $location = public_path('/images/') . $filename;
  Image::make($image)->resize(1200, 600)->save($location);
  if(!empty($page->image)){
    Storage::delete('images/' . $page->image);
  }
  $page->image = $filename;            
}
```

Comment: Pero el OP no está guardando los archivos en la carpeta `public` de raíz, más bien, los está guardando en `storage/app/public` que a mi parecer, si son archivos subidos por usuarios está mejor organizado el proyecto de esa forma y usar la carpeta `public` sólo para archivos que necesite la página, css, js, assets de imagenes, etc... Pero bueno, eso último supongo es gusto de cada quien...

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez  la hora de mostrarlas se le hara mas complicado ya que primero debe cambiar los permisos a escritura en esa carpeta luego de que debe dar acceso o hacer un `get_content` para traerla?? en cuestiones de seguridad prefiero solo dar permisos de escritura o la carpeta public unicamente!

Comment: Para nada, al crear un proyecto esa carpeta `public` (valga la redundancia) dentro de `storage` tiene los permisos (755) necesarios, para que tenga acceso al igual que en la carpeta `public` que se encuentra en raíz, para guardar imagenes sólo registraría el disco en `filesystems.php` (ó usar `storage_path()`) y usando el facade `Storage` y especificando te ahorras estar indicando toda la ruta completa, para traer la imagen con el link simbólico sólo sería necesario usar `asset('storage/imagen.jpg')`, mucho más organizado y nada complicado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una ruta en tu aplicación donde únicamente se ejecute ese comando `php artisan storage:link`, pero antes deberás borrar el link simbólico que generaste en tu entorno local. Una vez que borres el link simbólico accede a tu ruta la cual debe tener el siguiente código

```
Route::get('/turuta', function(){
  Artisan::call('storage:link');
});
```